# Serialized access to Collection with the use of ConcurrentLinkedQueue<T>

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent, java-threads

I have the following question concerning Java 7 ConcurrentLinkedQueue. Let us assume that I have the following class:

```
public class Blah {
    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> queue;

    public Blah() {
        queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String>();
    }

    public void produce(String action, String task) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized(queue) {
            while(queue.size() >= 8) 
                queue.wait();
            queue.add(action + "#" + task);
            queue.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public void consume() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized(queue) {
            while(queue.size() <= 0)
                queue.wait();
            String element = queue.poll();
            StringTokenizer strTok = new StringTokenizer(element, "#");
            String action = strTok.nextToken();
            String task = strTok.nextToken();
            /**
             * Operate on request
             */
            queue.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

The produce and consume functions will be called by concurrent threads in order to generate/remove threads for/from the list. I implement the previous functions consume() and produce() so that I serialize the addition/removal of elements in my queue. Is the above required, or ConcurrentLinkedQueue takes care of that? I am asking because I do not want to reduce the performance of my code.

Thank you,
Nick

Comment: Why on earth are you synchronizing??

Comment: @Boris Because I want all the operations inside the critical section to be executed atomically.

Comment: It's a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`. It guarantees atomicity and visibility if used correctly. You are coercing a non-blocking `Queue` into a [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html). **Don't**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: You are using a `Queue` specifically designed to be non-blocking as a [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).

Your code can be rewritten as:

```
public class Blah {
    private BlockingQueue<String> queue;

    public Blah() {
        queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(8);
    }

    public void produce(String action, String task) throws InterruptedException {
        while (true) {
            queue.put(action + "#" + task);
        }
    }

    public void consume() throws InterruptedException {
        while (true) {
            final String[] data = queue.take().split("#");
            final String action = data[0];
            final String task = data[1];
        }
    }
}
```

The `BlockingQueue` is bounded at `8` elements. `put` will block if the queue is full. `take` will block if the queue is empty.

No synchronization is required.

Also, `StringTokenizer` is deprecated. I would suggest you use a `class` something like:

```
public class Data {
    private final String action;
    private final String task;

    public Data(final String action, final String task) {
        this.action = action;
        this.task = task;
    }

    public String getAction() {
        return action;
    }

    public String getTask() {
        return task;
    }
}
```

To exchange data. There is no reason to create and parse `String`s.

Answer (score 1):

You did reduced the performance of your code as you are using the built-in synchronization which is the 'slowest' from the synchrnoization mechanism.

You have a perfect use case for `BlockingQueue`. Which provides you with `put` and `take` operations which blocks till space/element is available.

`ConcurrentLinkedQueue` offers you only thread safety not synchronization. It means you can safely add/remove elements from the queue in multithreaded application but it does not provide you with mechanism for waiting for space/elemetns, so you correctly used the wait(), notify() methods for that purpose (though you could synchronized on any other shared object as well, it did not have to be that queue). Using Lock instead of synchronized is much faster in Java.

Comment: the main reason I wanted to have a synchronized block is because I want the operate on request part of the code to be executed in an atomic fashion.

Comment: I dont know what you mean by request part of your code, I don't see such thing. The BlockingQueue add() implements exactly this part of code: while(queue.size() >= 8) 
                queue.wait();
            queue.add(action + "#" + task);
            queue.notifyAll(); but in more efficient manner

Answer (score -2):

Assuming that `produce` and `consume` will be called independently, you will probably end up with an infinite loop, as both attempt to lock the queue object and thus once `consume` doesn't find any elements it will never release the lock preventing produce from ever adding elements. The synchronization logic should probably be implemented in the methods calling `consume` and `produce`.

Comment: their release the lock in wait() operation.